# Output JSON file with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently practicing with Node.js and express. I have created a JavaScript object that I am scripting to output as a dropdown list. So far everything works as I want it to. Now I have created a model with mongoose and saved it. In my controller I parse this JSON file back into an object. How can I now incorporate this object back into my script so that I can output the content in my dropdown list?

```
mock.js
    
    const bikeArray = {
      Mountainbike: {
        Cross: {
          Größe: ["395 mm", "440 mm", "480 mm", "535 mm"],
          Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
          Bremsen: [
            "Shimano Deore BRM6000",
            "Shimano Deore BRM7000",
            "Shimano RX810 1x11",
          ],
          Schaltung: [
            "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
            "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
            "Shimano GRX 810 Di2 2x11",
          ],
          Reifen: [
            "Continental X-King (35-622)",
            "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
            "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
          ],
          Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
          Schloss: [
            "kein Schloss",
            "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
            "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
          ],
          Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
        },
        Hard: {
          Größe: ["395 mm", "440 mm", "480 mm"],
          Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
          Bremsen: [
            "Shimano Deore BRM6000",
            "Shimano Deore BRM7000",
            "Shimano RX810 1x11",
          ],
          Schaltung: [
            "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
            "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
            "Shimano GRX 810 Di2 2x11",
          ],
          Reifen: [
            "Continental X-King (35-622)",
            "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
            "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
          ],
          Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
          Schloss: [
            "kein Schloss",
            "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
            "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
          ],
          Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
        },
    };
 export {bikeArray};
```

bike.js

```
import  {bikeArray}  from './server/models/Category.js';


  window.onload = function () {
    var typSel = document.getElementById("typSel"),
      modelSel = document.getElementById("modelSel"),
      sizeSel = document.getElementById("sizeSel"),
      colorSel = document.getElementById("colorSel"),
      breakSel = document.getElementById("breakSel"),
      tireSel = document.getElementById("tireSel"),
      shiftSel = document.getElementById("shiftSel"),
      mudSel = document.getElementById("mudSel"),
      lockSel = document.getElementById("lockSel"),
      lightSel = document.getElementById("lightSel");
  
    for (var typ in bikeArray) {
      typSel.options[typSel.options.length] = new Option(typ, typ);
    }
  
    //Give Model
    typSel.onchange = function () {
      modelSel.length = 1; //remove all options first
      sizeSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      for (var model in bikeArray[this.value]) {
        modelSel.options[modelSel.options.length] = new Option(model, model);
      }
    };
  
    typSel.onchange();
  
    //Give Size
    modelSel.onchange = function () {
      sizeSel.length = 1;
      colorSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      var size = bikeArray[typSel.value][this.value];
      console.log(size);
      for (var sizeVar = 0; sizeVar < size.Größe.length; sizeVar++) {
        sizeSel.options[sizeSel.options.length] = new Option(
          size.Größe[sizeVar],
          size.Größe[sizeVar]
        );
      }
    };
    //Give Color
    sizeSel.onchange = function () {
      colorSel.length = 1;
      breakSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      var color = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
      console.log(color);
      for (var colorVar = 0; colorVar < color.Farbe.length; colorVar++) {
        colorSel.options[colorSel.options.length] = new Option(
          color.Farbe[colorVar],
          color.Farbe[colorVar]
        );
      }
    };
    //Give Breaks
    colorSel.onchange = function () {
      breakSel.length = 1;
      tireSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; //done
      var breaks = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
      console.log(breaks);
      for (var breakVar = 0; breakVar < breaks.Bremsen.length; breakVar++) {
        breakSel.options[breakSel.options.length] = new Option(
          breaks.Bremsen[breakVar],
          breaks.Bremsen[breakVar]
        );
      }
    };
  
    //Give Tires
    breakSel.onchange = function () {
      tireSel.length = 1;
      shiftSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      var tires = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
      for (var tireVar = 0; tireVar < tires.Reifen.length; tireVar++) {
        tireSel.options[tireSel.options.length] = new Option(
          tires.Reifen[tireVar],
          tires.Reifen[tireVar]
        );
      }
    };
    //Give Shift
    tireSel.onchange = function () {
      shiftSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      var shift = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
      for (var siftVar = 0; siftVar < shift.Schaltung.length; siftVar++) {
        shiftSel.options[shiftSel.options.length] = new Option(
          shift.Schaltung[siftVar],
          shift.Schaltung[siftVar]
        );
      }
    };
    //Give Mudguard
    shiftSel.onchange = function () {
      mudSel.length = 1;
      lockSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      var mud = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
      for (var mudVar = 0; mudVar < mud.Schutzblech.length; mudVar++) {
        mudSel.options[mudSel.options.length] = new Option(
          mud.Schutzblech[mudVar],
          mud.Schutzblech[mudVar]
        );
      }
    };
    //Give Lock
    mudSel.onchange = function () {
      lockSel.length = 1;
      lightSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      var lock = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
      for (var lockVar = 0; lockVar < lock.Schloss.length; lockVar++) {
        lockSel.options[lockSel.options.length] = new Option(
          lock.Schloss[lockVar],
          lock.Schloss[lockVar]
        );
      }
    };
    //Give Light
    lockSel.onchange = function () {
      lightSel.length = 1;
      if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
      var light = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
      for (var lightVar = 0; lightVar < light.Licht.length; lightVar++) {
        lightSel.options[lightSel.options.length] = new Option(
          light.Licht[lightVar],
          light.Licht[lightVar]
        );
      }
    };
  };
```

bikeController:

```
require("../models/database");
const Category = require("../models/Category");

/**
 *  Get /
 * Homepage
 */

 exports.bike = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    Category.find({}).then((bike) => {
      const array = JSON.stringify(bike);
      const obj = JSON.parse(array);
      console.log(obj);
      res.render('./layouts/index');
    }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    })
    
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: error.message || "Error Occured" });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> res.render('./layouts/index');

You can just pass the data (as an object) to your template engine like this

```
res.render('./layouts/index', obj);
```

Simple as that.

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: If I include the object with the render method in my Index.ejs how can I use the object in my script?

Comment: It depends on the template engine you’re using

Comment: I use ejs. Which one can you recommend

Comment: I use ejs as well. It’s good enough. In ejs, you can simply access your object just like you access it before you pass it to template engine. For instance, <%= obj.index %> prints that index in your object etc.